# mysql - Improve select performance for mobile number search

Tags: mysql, performance, search, wildcard

We have one million records of contact information in a MySQL database. The mobile number field is indexed, and when I search for mobile  number (all numeric) without any wildcards (Mobile_Number='number'), the response is pretty fast - it takes negligible time to respond.

However, the mobile number is not always stored in a same format, sometimes they precede with country code (for ex: +919876543210 etc) - so we are forced to always search with wildcards (like '%number%'). And when we do this, it looks like MySQL has to scan all the records and the response time takes about 0.6 secs on a core-i7, but our production server, as of now, is not a high performance box, and takes about 1.2 secs.

We need to improve this performance. I realized the following:

1) Since we are using like "%number%", the database cannot make use of the index.

2) I cannot make use of full text search, because these are not words.

3) We may have to clean up the data, and ensure that phone numbers are of the same format across all the records, so we can avoid using wildcard searches.

Is there any way, that we can improve the search time -- without changing the data in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: This involves a database change, but you could add a new column which contains a normalized version of the mobile number without changing the existing field. You could write a function that converts any existing number into a strict known format (always the same number of characters) and when searching put your search string through the same function so you are doing an exact search which should be quick if indexed. This is only helpful if the normalizing function is reliable and deterministic.  I'd strip out all dashes and put leading zeroes to pad where needed, for example.

Comment: To make even less an impact to the database, you could make a new table with just normalized numbers and using the same key. The search on the normalized table would give you the key to do the record retrieval from the original table.

Comment: Do they prepend only the contry code, but the end of the number is fixed ? If yes than store numbers in another column (say `reverse_number` column) in reverse order, for example: 9876543210=>0123456789, +919876543210=>012345678919+, and when you want to find a number 0123456789, use `WHERE reverse_number LIKE concat( reverse('0123456789'), '%')`, it will be very fast if you create an index for this additional column.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, the table is not static and records are added on a frequent basis. So the logic of storing the same format will need to be done on both existing records and code that handles new records. However, this is not an issue and we can handle by replacing existing records with the format that we want.

Comment: @kordiko: That is an interesting idea. Will try that out.